# $location.path not redirecting in Angular Service on mobile when used with Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope

I have a angular service that redirects to url after authentication.

The code

```
                $location.path(url);
```

Works fine on all the browsers. I am packaging this angular code as iOS and Android apps using Cordova. The above redirection code is not working on the mobile simulators though.

Here is the complete service code.

```
app.service('OCRoles', ['$resource', '$rootScope', '$location', function($resource, $rootScope, $location) {
this.load = function(roleList, url) {

    $resource('infra/assets/resources/config/roles.json').get(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data.Roles, function(key) {
            if (key[roleList] !== undefined) {
                $rootScope.roleConfig = key[roleList];
            }
        });
        if (url !== undefined) {
            console.log("URL IN OC roles "+ url);

            $location.path(url);
        }
    });
};
return this;
```

}]);

Comment: Try `$location.url(url);`

Comment: Tried. Redirection failed with this too

Comment: You are trying to redirect outside of the AngularJS application, try to use   `$rootScope.$apply(function () {
       $location.path(url);
    });`

Comment: @Aleksey Kiyanov in that case it should not work for browsers too ??

Comment: @ Aleksey Kiyanov. Its working fine on the browsers. Not working only when packaged as Cordova app. Wondering if $location.path(url); method behaves differently on browser and native webview.

Comment: Are you able to debug your application and see logs or maybe some errors?

Comment: Tried to debug and checked the logs. Focus coming till this statement and getting executed but the navigation is not happenning. No errors whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems not to be with `$location.path(url);`

I was using `$cookieStore` to validate the user authentication. For some strange reason,`$cookieStore` is working fine on browser but failing on the mobile web views.